# Meteor-Angular Service function

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I'm creating an app in Angular-Meteor, and i'd like create a few functions in my services which I can use in my controllers. However those functions use the $meteor.subscribe function, which queries the database and returns a call back. In my controller I want to call that function and bind that to the $scope, but then it returns undefined, because the call back hasn't returned anything yet. Is there a solution to keep the code in the service? Any tips?

An example:

Service

```
angular.module('GQ').service('AuthService', ['$meteor', function($meteor)
{

    console.log('AuthService init')

    this.getUserAuth = function() {

        var user = {};
        $meteor.subscribe('isAdmin').then(function(res){
            //do database query...

            //loop over returned values and do a check if query matches or not
            // if it does match return true
            // else return false



        });

        // then return the value

        return user.isAdmin;
    }


}]);
```

Controller

```
$scope.isAdmin = AuthService.getUserAuth();
console.log($scope.isAdmin) <--- undefined
```

Comment: Actually it is happening due to `async` behavior of ajax call. You should try `$q` service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use angular promises ([official doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)).

Example for your service:

```
this.getUserAuth = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var user = {};
    $meteor.subscribe('isAdmin').then(function(res, err){
        // ....

        // just an example
        if (!res.isAdmin) deferred.reject('not an admin');

        if (err) deferred.reject(err);
        else deferred.resolve(res);

    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Use in your controller:

```
AuthService.getUserAuth()
   .then(function(res){
       console.log(res); // the res from service
       $scope.isAdmin = res; // is asynchronous, but angular updates the scope var
    }, function(err){
       // error handling here
    });
```

Comment: Is this recommended practice? I also want to keep code in the service/factory files like @Marciano

Comment: With this you keep your code in sevice and facory files (this is recommended). I don't know the recommendations from MeteorJs, but I've seen this multiple times and in javascript it's recommended to use Promises for asynchronous processes. An alternative would be the use of callbacks.

Comment: @dork Yes this is recommended practice. Getting data into your services is convenient because you simply inject your service in your controller and share data between diverse controllers. Controllers shouldn't do the data fetching. It should only bind the data to the view.

Comment: @fdelia @Marciano Thanks! I've been seeing a lot of `Meteor.call`s in controllers that should be in services/factories and was wondering how to separate the code.